# Options on the E-mini S&P 500 Futures at the CME: when were EW3, the weekly Monday options and the weekly Wednesday options introduced?

Tags: united-states, investing, options

I read on [Historical First Trade Dates](http://www.cmegroup.com/media-room/historical-first-trade-dates.html#equityIndices) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170817030059/http://www.cmegroup.com/media-room/historical-first-trade-dates.html)) the introduction dates of options on the E-mini S&P 500 Futures at the [Chicago Mercantile Exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago_Mercantile_Exchange) (CME) :

> - E-mini options: 09/09/97
> - End-of-month Options on E-mini S&P 500: 05/21/06
> - Weekly Options on E-mini S&P 500:
>
>   - Weeks 1 & 2: 8/24/09
>   - Week 4: 7/06/10

When were EW3, the weekly Monday options (E1A,E2A,E3A,E4A,E5A) and the weekly Wednesday options (E1C,E2C,E3C,E4C,E5C) introduced?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why do you care? In any case, you can easily Google the answer...

> Effective Sunday, April 2, 2017 for trade date Monday, April 3, 2017, and pending all relevant CFTC
>   regulatory review periods, Chicago Mercantile Exchange Inc. (“CME” or “Exchange”) will list Monday
>   Weekly Options on the E-mini Standard and Poor’s Stock Price Index Futures and Standard and Poor’s
>   500 Stock Price Index Futures contracts (collectively the “Contracts”) for trading on CME Globex and for
>   submission for clearing via CME ClearPort as described in Appendix A below. Appendix B below provides
>   the Exchange fee schedule for the Contracts. [source](http://www.cmegroup.com/notices/ser/2017/03/SER-7865.pdf)

Comment: If nobody cared, why would there be a [Historical First Trade Dates](http://www.cmegroup.com/media-room/historical-first-trade-dates.html#equityIndices) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170817030059/http://www.cmegroup.com/media-room/historical-first-trade-dates.html))  page? I'm also looking for EW3 by the way.

Answer (score 1):

The traditional E-mini S&P500 options (introduced on 09/09/97) already expire on the 3rd Friday, so there's no need for another "weekly" option that expires at the same time.

Comment: Thanks. Isn't the traditional E-mini S&P500 option quarterly? If so, how about the remaining the 3rd Friday of January, the 3rd Friday of February, the 3rd Friday of April, etc.?